# how to specify which lettuce scenario to run

Tags: python, testing, lettuce

how to specify which lettuce scenario to run?

in using python lettuce test framework, I ran frequently into this case, one scenario failed and then I want to zoom in to this scenario to fix this scenario

can we specify which lettuce scenario to run in the feature file ?

Comment: you should search before asking here: http://lettuce.it/reference/cli.html#running-only-some-scenarios-of-a-specific-feature-file

Comment: @JohnWang do you know how to insert SPACE into the table column in the lettuce test case? this is puzzling me for a while as well. though I should read documentation carefully as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the [documentation](http://lettuce.it/reference/cli.html#running-only-some-scenarios-of-a-specific-feature-file) specified by JohnWang we have documentations like this to achieve:

```
lettuce xxx.feature -s 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use tags for the desired tests. For example:

```
    Scenario: Set off time in free time slot
        Given I click first free time slot
        And I choose menu item "Off"
        And I enter time that is in free interval
        When I click button "Ok"
        Then I see offtime time slot with title that matches with saved interval

    @wip
    Scenario: Set free time on off time
        Given I click last off time slot
        And I choose menu item "Set working"
        And I enter time that is in last off interval
        When I click button "Ok"
        Then I see freetime time slot with title that matches with saved interval
```

Then when you run lettuce just use

> ./manage.py harvest -t wip

It will run only those scenarios that are marked with tag **@wip**, in my case **wip** is for Work in Progress

If it is without django and just lettuce then use

> lettuce -t wip

Comment: this seems to be integrating with DJANGO, right ? will it work out of DJANGO ?

Comment: Thanks! This is not documented yet: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/lettuce-developers/GXAaxluNeAE