# Can lettuce scenarios have more than one tag?

Tags: python, tags, scenarios, lettuce

This is similar to the question [how to specify which lettuce scenario to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154822/how-to-specify-which-lettuce-scenario-to-run)

In the question they give an example of one tag being used per scenario. I was wondering if I can add on more tags, like in TestNG you can add on multiple groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/lettuce-developers/GXAaxluNeAE) it says yes, you can apply more than one tag

```
@wip @slow
Feature: annual reporting
  Some description of a slow reporting system.
```

From what I have seen, lettuce's documentation still does not include such feature.

My advice is to drop lettuce if you can and use [behave](https://pythonhosted.org/behave/index.html) instead.